# Consider the set $l^\infty$ of all bounded sequences of real numbers. Show that $d$ is well-defined for all pairs of sequences in $l^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

$l^\infty = d(\bf{x},y) = \sup_{n > 0} |x_n - y_n|$

I am having a hard time figuring out how to show it is well-defined. We are to show $d(x,y)$ is always defined. I know that well-defined is essentially saying that every input value is associated with an output value. Therefore, any sequence $x_n$ and $y_n$ I am using, there is a particular value that the two sequences converges to, given we are in the $l^\infty$ metric space? Pardon me if I am confusing anyone -- I am even confusing myself and I am self-learning the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By well-defined we mean that for every $x,y\in \ell^\infty$ we have that the supremum $\sup_n|x_n-y_n|$ exists (and is finite), so that $d:\ell^\infty\times\ell^\infty\to \mathbb R^+$ is actually a funtion. Now for any $n\in \mathbb N$ and $x,y\in \ell^\infty$ we have, by the triangle inequality, that $|x_n-y_n|\leq |x_n|+|y_n|$. As this is true for any $n$ we must have $$\sup_n|x_n-y_n|\leq \sup_n(|x_n|+|y_n|)=\sup_n|x_n|+\sup_n|y_n|.$$ Finally we can use the fact that $x$ and $y$ are bounded sequences to get that the right hand side of this inequality is finite. Thus, for any $x,y\in \ell^\infty$, the set $\{|x_n-y_n|:n\in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded above,and so the supremum exists, and $d$ is well defined.

Comment: Perfectly explained. I really appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: @Ryan Glad to help.